# com.google.GCKError Code=2 when connecting to ChromeCast device

Tags: ios, ios7, runtime-error, chromecast

I'm working on an iOS app where I now want to integrate ChromeCast support. I use the [HelloGoogleVideoCast](https://github.com/googlecast/CastHelloVideo-ios/tree/master/HelloVideoGoogleCast) example to test my hardware setup and get inspiration for my app.

I have now stumbled on a problem that is present both in my app and in HelloGoogleVideoCast. When I connect to a device (connectToDevice method in HelloGoogleVideoCast) I get error "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.google.GCKError error 2.)". I have power-cycled the device with no change in behavior. I never get to the callback deviceManagerDidConnect, instead deviceManager:didFailToConnectWithError is called with this error. Still, I can connect with the iOS YouTube app.

I can't find anything with substance if I google it and I can't find any good ChromeCast developer forums.

Is there anybody who has an inroad to how to solve this?

Comment: Can u please upload your app screenshot in the chromecast console (https://cast.google.com/publish/#/overview)

Comment: I'm not sure what that would accomplish?

Comment: What's your app status?

Comment: What do you mean? I have downloaded the project and am now running it in iOS simulator.

Comment: I have now tried it on my iPhone and I don't get this error. Has to be something with the iOS simulator.

Comment: M8! Don't debug chromecast on simulator :/

Comment: Error codes are here: https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/ios/g_c_k_error_8h
Your error code is a timeout error code. What receiver are you using Can you try CastVideos-ios app to see if that works for you?

Comment: Same problem happened to me  Screenshot: [link}(http://imgur.com/ARC2eWT) I also used the hello text IOS version

Answer (score 0):

I m not sure it will help but u can try:

Download the Chromecast app from app store:
[chromecast link](https://itunes.apple.com/il/app/chromecast/id680819774?mt=8)

After u see your `chromecast` -> select your `chromecast` -> General -> make sure both check box are selected (I know the text is nothing to do with your problem).

Try now.

If the error still occur, try to reboot your `chromecast`.

If your error still occur, try to reset your `chromecast`, and then check the boxes again (don't forget!).

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't change anything.

Comment: Can u please upload your app screenshot in the chromecast console (cast.google.com/publish/#/overview)

Comment: Is this something I can do with iOS apps?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you initialize the Receiver Manager in your receiver app as soon as possible. Don't wait for the window.onload. If the receiver takes too long to load and initialize the receiver manager, the connection is automatically torn down.﻿

Comment: Could you clarify what exactly needs to be done "quickly" here? Do you mean loading the `cast_receiver.js`, calling `cast.receiver.CastReceiverManager.getInstance()`, or calling `manager.start()`? I just spent a day debugging a `TIMEOUT` result in the Android `OnResult` callback following the latest firmware update. Upon recommendation by a developer on the Chromecast help forum, I simply moved `<script src="[...]/cast_receiver.js">` from `<body>` to `<head>` and left everything else alone. This did fix the problem, however I want to make absolutely sure that a similar issue won't occur again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you did and making the following changes on receiver worked for me:

- I've put the script src="//www.gstatic.com/cast/sdk/libs/receiver/2.0.0/cast_receiver.js" inside head tag and before title tag;
- I've put my script file which managed all cast functions after
  body tag (actually I've put all script declarations, except for cast_receiver, after body tag, including jQuery);

I hope it can help you yet :)